# Running a single step of a chain of ivy projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ivy

I'm trying to enable users to run a single project from a chain of ivy projects (in Jenkins.)

I tried to use ,in the post-build section, a conditional step ( 
[conditional step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUCzB.jpg))

Apart from the fact that it was running same evaluation **twice,** (and it did evaluate correctly - to 'false') it ignore itself and continue to the next step ....

```
11:50:20 [Boolean condition] checking [false] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${run.chain})
11:50:20 Run condition [Boolean condition] preventing perform for step [[Trigger parameterized build on other projects]]
11:50:20 [Boolean condition] checking [false] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${run.chain})
11:50:20 Run condition [Boolean condition] preventing perform for step [Builder to mark whether executed]
11:50:20 Triggering a new build of DAL ...
```

I also tried to use the fail plugin ([fail plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQjKf.jpg)) in order to "abort" the step and discontinue to next step (next project) but the build section in the configuration screen was removed and replaced by the ivy section so I cannot use this plugin as well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is... If each ANT project that uses ivy publishes it's artefacts to a common repository, then it should be possible to run any build in isolation, provided the repository has been initialised by at least one build run of each module in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Sorry for not being clear. The current situation of running a chain of build-project steps (with ivy) is working fine. The problem is when I want to run only one step. running any such step will trigger the next step and so on ...